# Is there a easier way to include $dialog bootstrap-ui component into our code

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am wondering if there is better way to include the $dialog module in angular code.

Please look at this plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/yXf1kNMqhAdo3iM8dFBy

All it does is open a modal upon clicking a button. 
But setting up this modal is messy as I have to put the code in the main controller (which is TestCtrl incase of my plunkr)

Does anyone know how to make this into a directive so that I can simply have it in my template like
Click here to open modal

Thanks,

Comment: are you referring to the modal dialog in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/?

Comment: That looks about right to me, how would you hope it would be.

Comment: @akonsu yes, it is the angular bootstrap dialog.

Comment: @Asok plnkr.co is currently down

Comment: You can access the plnkr now. I would rather just have a directive that I can add as a attribute to the button. <button modal-open> click here</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your code, but if you create a directive, you can move the controller code to the directive link function and output the DOM elements through the template property of the directive.

Even if you don't want to mess with the template replacement, you can at least move the code from the controller into the directive and just have the modal html as a hidden area in the main view. I have done that whenever I have used modal.

Here is a plunkr I did that illustrates pulling the controller code into a directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/3esMvm?p=preview

Comment: BoxerBucks.. since I am new to Angular.. I am kind of lost where to start adding this code into a directive... any clue you can give is helpful. At the end of the day I would prefer having it as <button modal-open>Click Here to Open </button> With the "modal-open" directive having all the relevant code. I hope you get the idea. Btw the plunker website is now up

Comment: Sure, there you go. I added a plunkr. Its more or less how I would do it.